# Configure Passport to accept request without body?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to set a LocalStrategy with the possibility to login without credentials given in request body

```
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin', {failureFlash : true}), function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
});
```

Here's the strategy :

```
passport
    .use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    }, 
    function (req, email, password, done) {
        if (email.length > 0 && password.legnth > 0) {
             /** Do some stuff with credentials **/
        }
        else {
             console.log('method2');
             /** Other method to log in with request headers...**/
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, when I post a request to `/signin` without body, I have a status 400 error, and the strategy isn't loaded (in the example I don't have `method2` written in console).

Is there a way to configure Passport to accept request without body?

For information, I use AngularJS front-end, requests made with `$http.post('/signin');`

passport version : **0.2.1**

passport-local version : **1.0.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `passport.authenticate` middleware inside another something like this

```
app.post('/signin', myPass, function(req,res){res.send(req.user)});

function myPass(req, res, next){
    // do your thing
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', {failureFlash : true})(req, res, next);
    // ^ this returns a middleware that you gotta call here now ^
}
```

Comment: Nice idea ! I saw the 400 error was handled by Passport middleware and I suggested the middleware creator to add a new option in the local strategy, to handle requests with no fields by ourselves : https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/pull/91/files

Comment: ah I'm a bit confused by this answer, how does it change anything, how does it prevent passport from throwing failure when there is no fields?

Comment: I made a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146947/passport-js-strategy-with-no-field-required
If you have some spare time can you possibly answer it or clear this a bit for me here?

Comment: the thing is that i want to put a new user inside done in passport strategy even if no password and username was supplied