# Passport.js strategy with no field required

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm surprised that it's so hard to find, or maybe something wrong with me.

I need a `passport.js` `strategy` that requires no fields - to run authentication with it on simple user `GET` request to `'/'` and manipulate user session data to, for example, make a new 'guest' user.

Maybe i can do this via passport `local-strategy`? Or am i need to create a custom one?

I saw this [Configure Passport to accept request without body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464091/passport-strategy-without-fields)  question, yet i just simply can't figure out how the suggested in answer wrapping will change anything.

Edit: here's what I'm trying to achieve

```
 passport.use('guest', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
},
function (req, NOusername, NOpassword, done) {
////NO PASSWORD OR USERNAME checks here, just deciding what kind of temporary user needs to be created///
if (req.session.passport) {
  ///create new user with previous session data
  done(null,user)
}
else {
   ///create clean user
   done(null, user)
})
)
```

and then in `routes.js`

```
app.get('/', passport.authenticate('guest'), function (req, res) {        
    res.render('PeerRoom.ejs', req.user);        
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Another approach could be using [`req.logIn`](http://passportjs.org/guide/login/) and skip dealing with the strategies altogether

```
app.get('/', yourCustomGuestAuthenticationMiddleware, function (req, res) {        
    res.render('PeerRoom.ejs', req.user);        
});
function yourCustomGuestAuthenticationMiddleware(req, res, next){
    // No need to do anything if a user already exists.
    if(req.user) return next();

    // Create a new user and login with that
    var user = new User({name: 'guest'+Math.random().toString() });
    user.save();
    req.logIn(user, next);
}
```

---

To make a new guest user, simply do it instead of rejecting an authentication

Here's a modified [example from the docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/)

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)  return done(err);
            if (!user) {

                /* HERE, INSTEAD OF REJECTING THE AUTHENTICATION */
                // return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });

                /* SIMPLY CREATE A NEW USER */
                var user = new User({ name: 'guest'+Math.random().toString() });
                user.save();
                /* AND AUTHENTICATE WITH THAT */
                return done(null, user);

            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: The thing is that im trying to do this without, in fact, authentication itself, i.e i want to create new guest user without checking for password and username at all, more of that user name nad password is not supplied at all, i want to run this strategy on simple GET request to main page

Comment: Added a code snipet that represents what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: I honestly never quite understood before what login function in passport does, am i getting it right, you can supply it with custom user and it will throw this user right into serialize/deserialize  passport session pipeline. If so, ah i feel a bit stupid then

Comment: also my web app is powered by sockets, which is opened shortly after user gets '/' and closes when he leaves. Therefore right now i implemented this user temporary guesting on socket connection (just manually created and added to session, separated from passport) and left passport just for handy registration/login strategies. If i understood the workflow of `login()` right then i need to rethink this again, yet for now  can't see a big difference in this approaches.
Ah, anyway just a thoughts aloud.